# Type conversion in the object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I'm trying to find the key in an object that has a third element in an array and then convert it to a number. What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Why do you want to write it one line? What's your objective?

Comment: So how is this different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542615/what-is-a-better-way-to-take-the-last-element-of-an-array-in-object

Comment: You really need to start selecting answers to your questions. You asked 10 questions, zero have selected answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find()` to find the array with at least 3 elements.

```
let number;
let arr = Object.values(numbersObject).find(a => a.length >= 3);
if (arr) {
  number = arr[2];
}
```

To do it in one line, use `||` to supply a default value if no array can be found:

```
let number = (Object.values(numbersObject).find(a => a.length >= 3) || [,,null])[2];
```